# Vertically centering div inside parent with viewport height

Tags: html, css, viewport

So I have this div with 100vh - 55px height, and I have a div inside that I want centered vertically inside the parent no matter what. How would I go on about doing this? This is what I have now:

```css
/* home.css | By Seb R | Ekchö */

.lander {
  height: calc(100vh - 55px);
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.lander .content {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top 30vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lander">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with **absolute positioning.**

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2uf9w4on/)

```css
.lander {

  height: calc(100vh - 55px);
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

}

.lander .content {

  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;  /* half height */

}
```

```html
<div class="lander">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

or **Flexbox**

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/se82pgzt/1/)

```css
.lander {
    height: calc(100vh - 55px);
    background: blue;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
}
.lander .content {
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lander">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Obviously at some point 300px might be larger your assigned viewport (as in the SO snippets) so you may need to adjust before that happens.

Comment: Flexbox worked like a charm! Thanks! I'll use mediaqueries for the heights.

Answer (score 2):

I just edited the code from above.

```
.lander .content {
  height: 30vh;
  top: calc((100vh - 30vh) / 2);
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

You are using px for the hight so css reads it as static size.

Comment: It is still offsetting as I make the window smaller in height. I need this to work on any display as it's responsive. I also need it to be fixed in height like the original.

Comment: I don't get your point sir. You want the height of your .content to be 300px and will remain even if you change the window smaller in height? or you want the .content to have 300px in height and will change if the window gets in to a small height?

Comment: I want .content to be vertically centered inside .lander (which has a dynamic height)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `:` missing in `margin-top 30vh;`

```css
/* home.css | By Seb R | Ekchö */

.lander {
  height: calc(100vh - 0px);
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.lander .content {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 30vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lander">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That still doesn't center the div vertically, only puts it on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
.lander .content {
background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
top: calc((100vh - 300px) / 2);
z-index: 9;
```

}

or

```
.lander .content {
background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
height: 300px;
margin-top: calc((100vh - 300px) / 2);
z-index: 9;
```

}

Comment: This doesn't work if the viewport height is really small, it will offset.

Comment: how about this
`lander .content {
   height: 30vh;
   top: calc((100vh - 30vh) / 2);
   background: red;
   position: relative;
}`